# Producer and Consumer in separate projects cause classnotfound when trying to deserialize

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ, Spring-Boot

1. I wrote Producer and send object a.b.MyObject to queue.
2. Wrote a consumer in another project(seperate JVM) which listens to queue and has the same object c.d.MyObject.

Because the package structure is different I am getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.MyObject

Making the same package structure resolves the issue which is little unfortunate. I guess I will add a bean to transfer jsons instead, not sure if that will resolve the package issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.MyObject

is a nature of Java Serialization and there is no other choice unless have the same class on the deserialization side.

Yes, JSON `MessageConverter` may help, if you configure it the proper [way](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#json-message-converter).

I mean `AbstractJavaTypeMapper.setIdClassMapping()`, where you can re-map an incoming `__TypeId__` (typically class) message header to the target local consumer's class.